# Deleting and copying from vector in R

Tags: r, vector

So I have this vectors in R:

```
V1 <- c("T", "G", "A", "T", "-", "A", "B")
V2 <- c("T", "G", "C", "T", "G")
```

And know i need to remove one position from v1, and copy v2 to the four first positions in order to get

```
c("T", "G", "C", "T", "A", "B")
```

Making 
`v1[1:5]<-v2[1:4]`obviously dont work.

Comment: The logic is not clear to me, can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?

```
new.v1 = c(v2[1:4], v1[6:length(v1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `head` and `tail`

```
c(head(V2, 4), tail(V1, 2))
```